# Angular 2 - Observables returning twice but after a few seconds...not sure why

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I have an Ionic 2 app with a function that's aggregating a bunch of data via observables. The data comes back...except it's not always complete on the first return. After a few seconds, my data gets returned again, except both instances are now populated with the complete data. It's really weird and I'm not sure what's causing it.

Here is my function:

```
getUserStories(data) {
    return this._af.database
      .object(`/social/users/${data.id}`)

      // Switch to the joined observable
      .switchMap((user) => {

        let connections = [];
        let connectionKeys = Object.keys(user.connections);

        return Observable.combineLatest(
          connectionKeys.map((connectionKey) => this._af.database
            .object(`/social/users/${connectionKey}`)
          ),
          (...connections) => {

            connectionKeys.forEach((connectionKey, index) => {

              this._af.database
                .object(`/social/user_stories_seen/${connectionKey}/${data.id}`).subscribe(data => {

                // Iterate over the connections and append the correct "last_seen" variable
                connections.forEach((connection, index) => {
                  if(connection.$key === connectionKey) {
                    connections[index]['last_seen'] = data;
                  }

                })
              });
            })
            return connections;
          });
      })
   }
```

Here is the view that calls this functionality:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {

    // Get the user from storage and get all the connections
    this.storage.get('user').then(data => {

      //Get the user profile
      this._users.getUserStories({id: data.id}).subscribe(stories => {
        console.log('stories', stories);
      });
    })
}
```

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have internal observables that are subscribing and then updating `last_seen` properties of the connections.

Those observables are not are not composed into the observable you are returning, so they can emit and update the connections *after* your `combineLatest` operator emits.

The implementation could be simplified by using a function that combines the connections and last-seen values:

```ts
getUserStories(data) {

  return this._af.database
    .object(`/social/users/${data.id}`)
    .switchMap((user) => {

      const getConnection = (connectionKey) => {
        return Observable.combineLatest(

          // Combine the connection and last-seen value:

          this._af.database
            .object(`/social/users/${connectionKey}`),
          this._af.database
            .object(`/social/user_stories_seen/${connectionKey}/${data.id}`),

          // Assign the last-seen value, but return the connection:

          (connection, seen) => {
            connection.last_seen = seen;
            return connection;
          }
        );
      };

      const connections = Object.keys(user.connections).map(getConnection);
      return Observable.combineLatest(...connections);
    });
}
```

Comment: Interesting, for some reason, when I run this function, I'm getting a runtime Error "data.splice is not a function": TypeError: data.splice is not a function
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:33596:34
    at Array.forEach (native)

Comment: Yeah, the fixes you made were good for resolving "this", but I'm getting that data.splice issue. I'm using RXJS 5.0.0-beta.12

Comment: oh snap, would this be better if I just updated rxjs, then?

Comment: So actually, I'm a bit confused at what needs to be done here. Are you saying to just abandon your answer and make the tweaks to my current function?

Comment: Man, I appreciate the answer, but unfortunately, it's still giving me that data.splice issue :/ When I try to update to the latest v5.0.3 rxjs, I get all sorts of warnings and an error from npm

Comment: Compose `do(connections => console.log(connections))` after the `switchMap`  and add some logging if it fails before that. I cannot see any array operations other than the args and the connection keys, so it's hard to see where this could be failing with that error.

Comment: So I figured out the issue was related to some code I was using after I'm subscribing to the function call. The function itself actually works flawlessly. I'm still noticing there are two instances of that call happening, even with that function :/ So it's still kinda doing what it was doing before :(

Comment: If you are not using the latest version of AngularFire2 (`beta.7`) you should update your dependency, as there have been bugs fixed that could be related to this. If the `object` observables are well behaved, the behaviour of the code in the question should differ from the code in the answer, as the code in the question does not compose the inner observable - it just subscribes to it (which is a bit of a problem, as there'll be no unsubscribe).

Comment: Alright, so after some more investigation, I'm a bit embarassed. It wasn't the function that was getting called multiple times, it was the component it self. So yes, the function works exactly as expected and it works wonderfully. Thankyou for this answer so much, it has been a blessing. I'll actually be able to use this in other situations as well :D Cheers!